# Eclipse + Java 14 + XML Libraries: Is there a step by step for reconfiguring projects and dependencies from java 8 to Java 14?

Tags: java, xml, eclipse

I am updating a java project from 1.8 compliance to 1.14 compliance.

In eclipse , anything coming from an XML library that used to be a system library in java 8 throws an error similar to "The package org.xml.sax is accessible from more than one module: , java.xml"

I have been through the Eclipse bug pages and determined that it is specifically an Eclipse issue (possible bug). Other people have worked around this with project settings and POM entries.  However, at no point have I found what those settings and entries were. I am left knowing there is a solution, and "kind-of" the nature of a solution, but no specifics.

The JRE system library in eclipse shows the javax.xml package as part of the module path.

The POM also contains the dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Any feedback would be appreciated.

The root cause appears to be how Eclipse interprets the packages in the system modules - it sees the XML modules twice. When I remove the javax.xml module from the system build path, the xml packages are not found. However, when I add it back in, the xml packages are found twice.

Than you in advance.

Comment: [Oracle JDK Migration Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/migrate/index.html#JSMIG-GUID-C25E2B1D-6C24-4403-8540-CFEA875B994A) It's for migrating from 8 to 11 which is close enough since 8 is non-modular and everything after 8 is modular.

Comment: This is close, but my problem is that Eclipse (and only Eclipse) is seeing two copies of the libraries. The code compiles fine under maven.

Comment: So then, can you detail how the project is currently set up, and confirm that it's already set to compile against Java 14 (there is no "1.14")?

Comment: The java 14 facet is enabled.  POM says <java.version>14</java.version>. Maven Project says it's using the java 14 libraries

Comment: It's a Java restriction, not an Eclipse bug: the same package must not be contained in more than one module. There was an Eclipse bug showing this error by mistake for a package `a.b` even if there was only a package `a.b.c`. But that bug was fixed a long time ago.